# Solve sympy ode for a specific value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy, differential-equations

I have:

```
from sympy import Function, dsolve, Derivative, exp, Eq
from sympy.solvers import solve
from sympy.abc import x, t
u = Function('u')


print("\nItem I\n")

edo_1 = u(t).diff(t) + 0.5*u(t) - exp(-t/2) - 500

y = dsolve(edo_1, u(t), ics={u(0): 0})
```

And want to get the result of "y" when t=10
I tried with solve and rhs, but I can't get my result. I know from calculating by hand that it should give me around 993.

Comment: `y.subs(t, 10)`?

Comment: What do you get?  What is `y` result?

Comment: Using `y.subs(t,10)` as @rickhg12hs suggests returns `u(10)=993.329432470905`, which is consistent with the value you expected.

Comment: To get the value itself rather than the equation you can use `y.rhs.subs(t, 10)`